# Checkout | Products from aborted purchase attempts are not deleted

Tags: checkout, onestepcheckout

I have a problem with the checkout. Products from aborted purchase attempts are not deleted.

the following scenario

The customer has only one product in his shopping cart.
In the checkout process (onepagecheckout), he must log in.
After logging in, the product of the aborted purchase attempt is also displayed in the CheckoutSteps.

I would like to turn it off.
We sell prints. Since there is only one product per order.

maybe someone has an idea

Comment: set your quote lifetime to minimum and also payment methods should disable quote after successful purchase

Comment: many thanks for your response.
I was a few days out of office.
I had this one more question.
Where do I set the the "quote lifetime"?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a feature.
For logged in customers the cart is kept FOREVER.
And when the user logs in again his current cart is merged with the previous one.
This happens in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::loadCustomerQuote`. 
see if you can remove something from that method.
inside this if statement is where the magic happens:  `if ($customerQuote->getId() && $this->getQuoteId() != $customerQuote->getId()) {`
I think you can remove this but not sure

```
$customerQuote->merge($this->getQuote())
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();
```